# How to add a custom button to java.awt.FileDialog?

Tags: java, awt

I am using `java.awt.FileDialog` to LOAD a file into my application.

By default, the options that are available while opening the file are "CANCEL" and "OPEN".

I want to add another button so that three options are shown in the FileDialog - "CANCEL", "OPEN", and "OPEN AND DO X".

How can I do this? This doesn't seem to be straightforward.

Comment: Why AWT rather than Swing?  See this answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Just to be able to use native OS UI elements.

Comment: I agree that Swing is the way to go over AWT, the link @AndrewThompson provided is a very good explanation of why. Can you give more details on what native OS UI elements you are trying to use? There may be a simple way to do it in Swing, and you can easily add buttons to a dialog in Swing as well